# Setting up Celery with Redis on a server for a Django app

Tags: django, redis, celery

I am trying to set up my django project to work with Celery and Redis. I have no issues running it locally, but I can't get it working in the production server.

My hosting recommends to setup Redis using unixsocket and run redis in a screen:

- port 0
- unixsocket /path/redis.sock

This all works, when I run redis I get:

```
* The server is now ready to accept connections at /here-comes-my-path/redis.sock
```

Now I have issues:

1. How do I verify the connection? `redis-cli -p 0` returns 
   `Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:0: Can't assign requested address
   not connected>`
2. How do I start celery worker? Running `celery -A rbwpredictor worker -l info` 
   returns (I've xed sensitive data):

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   ```

   File "/usr/home/xxxx/.virtualenvs/xxxx/bin/celery", line 6, in 
       from celery.**main** import main
     File "/home/xxx/domains/xxxx/public_python/xxxx/celery.py", line 6, in 
       from celery import Celery
   ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery'

My Celery settings in settings.py:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_STATUS_PENDING = 'PENDING'
CELERY_STATUS_STARTED = 'STARTED'
CELERY_STATUS_RETRY = 'RETRY'
CELERY_STATUS_FAILURE = 'FAILURE'
CELERY_STATUS_SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS'
```

As mentioned above locally everything works fine, it's the configuration on the server I struggle with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured redis to communicate through unix socket not through standard port

To connect with redis-cli you can use

```
redis-cli -s /here-comes-my-path/redis.sock
```

And you should reconfigure [redis.conf](https://redis.io/topics/config) or just set `BROKER_URL`

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis+socket:///here-comes-my-path/redis.sock'
```